# C# Multiple Client - Sending Nickname along with IP and port no

Tags: c#, sockets

I am working on a C# multithreaded socket program. Client side code for connecting is:

```
 c.Connect(ipText.Text, port);  // Can I add nickName here? probably not?
 thrReceive = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Receive)); //Receive -> accepts buffers from server
 thrReceive.Start();
```

Before I start with the problem, a quick view of what I want to do:
All data send by a client should be directed to all other clients but not the sender, so every time a client sends data, program should go over the list of clients and send the data.

What I am struggling with is along with port and IP, I want to send a nickname to the server. After that, server will check whether the nickname is unique. If not, it will reject the connection.

I thought of a trivial solution where client sends nickname with the sentence it sends, so this is after establishing connection with server. Server keeps a list of structs, lets say struct is called "param". "param" consists of 3 variables: 1)Socket 2)bool first = true 3)string nick

Whenever a new connection is established, a new "param" is created, initiating "first" to true and "nick" to empty string, and of course the socket to the client. And the very first time the same socket sends a data via a buffer, I will extract its nickname, set "first" to false and check its uniqueness, if not unique then disconnect the socket and delete the related entry.

I believe above solution is not a good solution, nothing near good actually:) There should be some proper way, I suppose.

Comment: You need to send a packet to the server after connecting. The server must accept in order to send data to it. Send something like Auth <Nickname> in your packet style and then let the server respond with yes or no (again in your packet style) and kick him from server if inavlid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not send data with the connection. That means you can not reject the connection but you can send packets for authenticating on the server. Example for that:

Client connects

Server accepts

Client sends something like "Auth [username]"

Server checks if username is free

If not: Server sends something like "RejectAuth" to the client and disconnects.

If it is free: Server sends something like "AcceptAuth" and the protocol continues (Sharing information, sending data, etc.)

Note: this is not the most optimal way. You could instead of disconnecting assign a random username and send him a change request. Thats much better because its faster and the user can send new usernames and instantly check if its free.

Comment: Is there any existing library for authentication or should I use buffers? I've done a little research yet couldn't find any. Someone says that sockets do not have authentication and this should be handled at application base. Am I the one who should write some function/class? If so, can you gimme some heads up?

Comment: @xCoder if you really want password auth you probably need a auth server. So a main server you send username and password and get a session key. Then you can send that session key to the server you are connecting to and the server will get the information from an api from the main server. If you just want to send username then just send it after connecting and wait for response ^^

Comment: I used key values when sending data to server. Any buffer send from client has a key value and server evaluates them and acts accordingly. i.e. if the key is nick, look into recorded clients... Thanks for your answers btw:)